# Generic type paramaters are not types?

Tags: c#, generics, types, typeof

I find the following a bit confusing....

```
Dictionary<Type, Object> _typeMap;

public void RegisterType<T>(Object o)
{
    _typeMap.Add(typeof(T), o);
}
```

Why is `typeof(T)` required in the `Add` method? Isn't the `T` type paramater already a `Type`? What else is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`T` is a type *name*, and `typeof` is used to retrieve the corresponding `Type` object.

A generic type parameter works exactly like just any other type name, say, `int`. You can't exactly do `typeMap.Add(int, 0);` either.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense. Maybe MSDN should refer to them as `type name paramaters` instead of `type paramaters`, would have saved me the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

No. `Add` here needs **an instance of a `Type` class**.

*Generic type parameters* are **not** instances of `Type` class.

Answer (score 0):

You hace to put the typeof(T) because T is the class definition, and the type is an object describing a Type, that for T and for Object and for String... etc etc.

typeof gets the Type of the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

This solution strikes me as a a bit of an "opps".  I *believe* that the result of the this code will always be to try to add an entry with key "Type" into the dictionary due to the fact that you are always get the "typeof" of a **Type**.  Instead I think what you are looking for is...

```
public void RegisterType<T>(Object o)
{
    _typeMap.Add(T, o);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You can't pass "T" to _typeMap.Add because "T" is not an expression.  You need an expression of type System.Type to pass to Add.